# Count all agents that are in certain state

Tags: simulation, anylogic

Community,

I would like to collect statistics on my "Customer" agent-population.
The agent population lives in main. The agent states are described according to the below screenshot.

In main, I want to store agent statistics in a DataSet. Therefore, I tried: `count(customers,c->c.inState(greenState))`

The following error message appears:

**"greenState" cannot be resolved to a variable.**

Could someone help me out and explain what is wrong and provide a solution?

Thank you very much! :)

[image: Statechart of Customer Agent]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reference the `greenstate` from where it exists inside your agent.
`count(customers,c->c.inState(Customer.greenState))`

Comment: Many thanks, Jaco-Ben. Is this also something one can learn in your Java for AnyLogic course? KR

Comment: Not this specifically, but loads of other things, more focussed on using Java to build simpler better models. Contact me for more details or for discount ;-)

Comment: @JHK you can learn this by doing the step-by-step tutorials in the AnyLogic help, or by following the "AnyLogic in 3 days" book or by doing a standard AnyLogic training course :)

Comment: @Jaco-BenVosloo Many thanks. I will definitely reach out to you!