# "cannot be resolved or is not a field" error in Anylogic event condition

Tags: java, anylogic

Please somebody help, I'm very new to Java and Anylogic!

I'm getting errors in the Condition part of the Event named "Upis_studenta_RI":

> Upisna_kvota_RI cannot be resolved or is not a field. Location: Model-1/Main/Upis_studenta_RI - Event
> potražnja_RI cannot be resolved or is not a field. Location: Model-1/Main/Upis_studenta_RI - Event
> Brucoši cannot be resolved or is not a field. Location: Model-1/Main/Upis_studenta_RI - Event

The code in Condition is:

```
studenti_Rijeka.inState(studenti_Rijeka.Brucoši)<=studenti_Rijeka.Upisna_kvota_RI &&
studenti_Rijeka.potražnja_RI>=studenti_Rijeka.Upisna_kvota_RI
```

"studenti_Rijeka" is agent in Main, "Brucoši" is State in statechart inside agent studenti_Rijeka,
"Upisna_kvota_RI" and "potražnja_RI" are parameters in same agent.

Here is the code (generated in AnyLogic)

```
 @Override
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public boolean testConditionOf( EventCondition _e ) {

    if ( _e == Upis_studenta_RI) return 
studenti_Rijeka.inState(studenti_Rijeka.Brucoši)<=studenti_Rijeka.Upisna_kvota_RI &&
studenti_Rijeka.potražnja_RI>=studenti_Rijeka.Upisna_kvota_RI 
;
    return super.testConditionOf( _e );
  }
```

And parameter potražnja_RI is coded:

```
     public 
double  potražnja_RI;

  /**
   * Returns default value for parameter <code>potražnja_RI</code>.
   * <i>This method should not be called by user</i>
   */
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public double _potražnja_RI_DefaultValue_xjal() {
    final Rijeka self = this;
    return 
50 
;
  }

  public void set_potražnja_RI( double value ) {
    if (value == this.potražnja_RI) {
      return;
    }
    double _oldValue_xjal = this.potražnja_RI;
    this.potražnja_RI = value;
    onChange_potražnja_RI_xjal( _oldValue_xjal );
    onChange();
  }
```

I'm obviously still missing the point how to use some parameter in expressions, and dont know how to properly post a question :-/

How to use parameter xy in agent abc (of type ABC) in event located in Main, if I want to make condition of event:  xy<5?
AnyLogic will returns error "xy cannot be resolved or is not a field".

Please help!

Comment: without seeing any code, we won't be able to respond to this

Comment: public boolean testConditionOf( EventCondition _e ) {

    if ( _e == Upis_studenta_RI) return 
studenti_Rijeka.inState(studenti_Rijeka.Brucoši)<=studenti_Rijeka.Upisna_kvota_RI &&
studenti_Rijeka.potražnja_RI>=studenti_Rijeka.Upisna_kvota_RI 
;
    return super.testConditionOf( _e );
  }

Comment: you should show all the relevant code, not just that bit. As far as we can see, there are no such variables declared/instantiated.

Comment: I'm confused because AnyLogic should do the coding if agents and parameters inside them are correctly created, so the error is probably that I dont know how to write condition for the event!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `inState(Statename)` you should reference the Agent type not the instance of the agent in order to get the statename.

For example
`count(customers,c->c.inState(Customer.greenState))`

Where `Customer` is the agent type (In capital letters)

See this question for a similar problem

I assume your code must then be

`studenti_Rijeka.inState(Studenti_Rijeka.Brucoši)`

if `studenti_Rijeka` is an instance of `Studenti_Rijeka`

Remember that you cant ask a population if it is in state, a population of agents is just a collection... you need to ask each individual agent in the state

for example

```
for (Rijeka rijeka:studenti_Rijeka) {
   if (riejka.inState(Rijeka.Brucoši)) {
      traceln("do something");
   }
}
```

[Count all agents that are in certain state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70698412/count-all-agents-that-are-in-certain-state/70698488#70698488)

Comment: I tried to put agent type, which is Rijeka:  studenti_Rijeka.inState(Rijeka.Brucoši),but now the error is: The method inState(Rijeka.statechart_state) is undefined for the type Main._studenti_Rijeka_Population. Location: Model-1/Main/Upis_studenta_RI - Event

Comment: You cant ask a population if it is in a certain state... you need to ask an agent in the population if it is in a state. Maybe add a screenshot and show exactly what you want to do. Do you want to find all the students that are in the state and do something with them?  See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for that, I understand now for counting in state "Brucoši"... I also tried to  replace it with statistic, the sum of agents in state Brucoši: studenti_Rijeka.Rijeka_Brucoši() ....and it worked.  But still getting errors for two parameters "Upisna_kvota_RI" and "potražnja_RI" in agent studenti_RI.

Comment: @Tomolesque This sounds like a second question, maybe ask it in a different. Remember to accept my answer if you found it helpful and upvote if you think it worthy ;-)